# If $\lim f(a_n)=L$ for every monotone decreasing sequence ${a_n}$ in $(-\infty,b)$ such that $\lim a_n=-\infty$, then $\lim f(x)=L$

Tags: limits

For $f:(-\infty,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(a_n)=L$ for every monotone decreasing sequence ${a_n}$ in $(-\infty,b)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=-\infty$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=L$

---

It makes me confused, because I aleardy know to prove for every sequence not only monotone decreasing

But I saw two problem(for all sequence and for monotone decreasing sequence) together.

It can be solved for all sequence, then why there is problem about only monotone decreasing sequence?

I think there is another method using monotone decreasing property, but I can't find it.

---

I tried to devide the cases; $L=-\infty$, $-\infty<L<\infty$, $L=\infty$

Maybe if $-\infty<L<\infty$ then I might use monotone convergent theorem, because it's bounded.

However, how about other cases?

Comment: Try to do this with the $\epsilon$ type definition of $\lim_{n\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)=L
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It amounts to show that, for any sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $a_{n}\rightarrow-\infty$, we have $f(a_{n})\rightarrow L$.

To show that $f(a_{n})\rightarrow L$, first we fix a subsequence $(f(a_{n_{k}}))$ of $(f(a_{n}))$, we are to show that, the subsequence has a further subsequence $(f(a_{n_{k_{l}}}))$ such that $f(a_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow L$.

The matter is then to choose such a further subsequence.

Note that $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow-\infty$, we want to choose further subsequence from here. Choose an $n_{k_{1}}$ such that $a_{n_{k_{1}}}<-1$, then choose an $n_{k_{2}}$ such that $n_{k_{2}}>n_{k_{1}}$ and that $a_{n_{k_{2}}}<-2$. Proceed in this way, then $(a_{n_{k_{l}}})$ is a strictly decreasing subsequence of $(a_{n_{k}})$ (and hence the so called further subsequence) that $a_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow-\infty$.

Now we exploit the assumption to deduce that $f(a_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow L$.

Comment: Oh, I've never thought about further subsequence. Thank you.